# Does the __init__ method in python mean the same as the Main method in C#?

Tags: python, c#, oop, methods

Not really sure whether this is the sort of thing to ask here but here we go.

I recently learnt the basics of OOP in python to help with a project. I moved onto C# as a sort of extension of that, so I could create games with Unity.

I was just wondering whether the main method in C# was the same as the `__init__` method in python?

Comment: It's a constructor method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom matches to the `public static Main()` method.

The `def __init__(self):` method matches to the constructor of a class in C#.

```cs
class X
{
    public X() { }  // constructor in C#: same name as the class and no return type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` method is used during class definitions, usually storing all predefined class variables, like:

```
class Basket:

   def __init__(size, material, color):
       self.size = size 
       self.material = material
       self.color = color
```

then when you create an instance of the class `Basket` and pass the positional arguments the `__init__` method uses them to create the object:

```
basket = Basket(20, 'rubber', 'brown')
```

then we can call the `basket` instance arguments like:

```
print(basket.size, basket.material)
```

Output:

```
20, brown
```